# Exceptions thrown when invoking endpoint with FeignClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-cloud-feign

```
GetMapping("/{id}")
public HttpServletResponse downloadFile(@PathVariable String id, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOEx/ception {
    // some logic
);
```

When invoking the endpoint above, it works as expected.

However, when invoked with `FeignClient` the following exceptions are thrown:

Exception 1:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException
```

Exception2:

```
feign.codec.EncodeException: Error converting request body
```

The error occurs even if there is no business logic

After investigation, it turned out that the `HTTPServletResponse` request parameter was causing this error.

Is it mentioned somewhere that `HTTPServletResponse` should not be passed as an argument at the level of endpoints?

Comment: would it not be the HttpServletRequest instead of HttpServletResponse that you would take in?

Comment: No, it was `HttpServletResponse` used to send a CSV file to the client.